# Weekly Schedule Expression For ECS Scheduled Task

Tags: amazon-ecs

We have created a scheduled job to be run every Friday at 4:00 Am. We want this job to run once every week.

But the job is unfortunately not running. I am not able to see task status in cloudwatch.

We have set up a job with the below expression.

```
Schedule expression cron(0 12 ? * 2 *)
```

Let me know if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above expression is correct. But AWS Uses GMT time while executing these tasks.

We can see the exact time of the task to be executed in CloudWatch rules.

```
CloudWatch -> Rules -> Name of the scheduled task
```

Output:

```
Schedule    
Cron expression 0 12 ? * 2 *
Next 10 Trigger Date(s) 
Mon, 29 Oct 2018 12:00:00 GMT
Mon, 05 Nov 2018 12:00:00 GMT
Mon, 12 Nov 2018 12:00:00 GMT
Mon, 19 Nov 2018 12:00:00 GMT
Mon, 26 Nov 2018 12:00:00 GMT
Mon, 03 Dec 2018 12:00:00 GMT
Mon, 10 Dec 2018 12:00:00 GMT
Mon, 17 Dec 2018 12:00:00 GMT
Mon, 24 Dec 2018 12:00:00 GMT
Mon, 31 Dec 2018 12:00:00 GMT
```